# Python merge multiple substrings

Tags: python, pandas, merge, substring, nan

I have the below dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jon','Alex','Jenny','Rick','Joe'], 'Color':['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Black', 'Yellow'], 'Tel':['3745 569', '785 985', '635 565a', '987', np.nan]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Phone':['987 856','985',np.nan, '569','459 56']})
```

I would like to :

1. find the common substring value stored in column df1['Tel'] and df2['Phone]
2. left merge df2, outputing the phone, the common substring value found in the df1['Tel'] and the df1['Colour'] column.

Expected Result:

[image]

What I have found and edited is a code that works only without NaN values and cannot search if the key is a substring like in my case:

```
a = ['Tel', 'Phone']
b = [1 ,2]
rhs ={}

for x,y in zip(a, b):
    rhs[y] = (df1[x].apply(lambda x: df2[df2['Phone'].str.find(x).ge(0)]['colour']).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly you want to merge by common substring. This code does this, albeit not very elegantly. But I kept it explicit to show potential pitfalls: this code assumes a match by longest substring (there might be shorter matches and indeed there might be multiple matches of the same common length; this code does not handle that, longest common substring from RosettaCode, ref. given).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring#Python
def longestCommon(s1, s2):
    len1, len2 = len(s1), len(s2)
    ir, jr = 0, -1
    for i1 in range(len1):
        i2 = s2.find(s1[i1])
        while i2 >= 0:
            j1, j2 = i1, i2
            while j1 < len1 and j2 < len2 and s2[j2] == s1[j1]:
                if j1-i1 >= jr-ir:
                    ir, jr = i1, j1
                j1 += 1; j2 += 1
            i2 = s2.find(s1[i1], i2+1)
    return len(s1[ir:jr+1])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jon','Alex','Jenny','Rick','Joe'], 'Color':['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Black', 'Yellow'], 
                    'Tel':['3745 569', '785 985', '635 565a', '987', np.nan]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Phone':['987 856','985', np.nan, '569','459 56']})

# left merge df2 to df1 via longest matching substring Tel to Phone
mrglst = []
for phone in df2['Phone']:
    lgstr = 0
    lgtel = ''
    lgcol = ''
    for tidx, trow in df1.iterrows():
        if str(phone) != 'nan' and str(trow['Tel']) != 'nan':
            thisstrl = longestCommon(phone, trow['Tel'])
            if thisstrl > lgstr:
                lgstr = thisstrl
                lgtel, lgcol = trow['Tel'], trow['Color']
    mrglst.append([phone, lgtel, lgcol])
    
dfmrg = pd.DataFrame(mrglst, columns=['Phone', 'Tel', 'Color'])
print(dfmrg)
```

This produces

```
     Phone       Tel  Color
0  987 856       987  Black
1      985   785 985   Blue
2      NaN                 
3      569  3745 569    Red
4   459 56  3745 569    Red
```

which is almost the desired output but for the last line: _56 matches to _56 Tel: this is correct but possibly an only-numeric-digits match is desired. In this case it might be better to clean the phone numbers prior to the match (also one of the numbers has an 'a' at the end so I went for a regular string match).